# MySQL table to JSON with strange output

Tags: php, json

I've this MySQL table:

```
TABLE `table1` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `First` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Second` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
)
```

And this PHP code that is used for query the table and encode its contents into a JSON object:

```
<?php
/* Connection stuffs*/

$query = " SELECT * FROM table1;";
$results = mysql_query($query);
$stuff = array();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($results))
        array_push($stuff,$row);
$ja = json_encode($stuff);
echo $ja;
?>
```

Now, the code is working but I get a strange output (I'm only posting one row for question's readability but the others are the same) :

```
{
    "0": "1",
    "ID": "1",
    "1": "ivh",
    "First": "ivh",
    "2": "gyt",
    "Second": "gyt"
}
```

My question is: Why `echo $ja;` doesn't print this?

```
{
        "ID": "1",
        "First": "ivh",
        "Second": "gyt"
    }
```

Where do `"0","1","2"` come from? Furthermore the `"0"` 's content is the same of `ID`, as well as `1-First` and `2-Second`. There kind of a relationship between the MySQL column number and the `$ja` contents.

I've also tried to use this query:

```
$query = " SELECT ID,First,Second FROM table1;";
```

But the results are the same. Could someone help me? Thanks!

Comment: Run a var_dump in your $stuff array before converting it to json and check out what's happening

Comment: Also instead of mysql_fetch_array try mysql_fetch_assoc so you can keep the column names too

Comment: My question has been marked as duplicate while I've searched on SO and  I've not found anything on this problem. @Phiter Fernandes Thanks for your reply, I've used mysql_fetch_assoc and now it is working properly. I can't mark your comment as answer because my question has been closed, I'm sorry. Thanks man!

Comment: Yeah someone else answered, apparently.

Comment: You've answered first , post it , I will mark! Thanks

Comment: I can't answer it anymore since the question has been closed. You can mark his answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggest you to use `mysql_fetch_assoc()` or [`mysql_fetch_array($results, MSSQL_ASSOC)`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php). It will return only columns instead of being duplicate

```
$query = " SELECT * FROM table1;";
$results = mysql_query($query);
$stuff = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($results, MSSQL_ASSOC))
{
    array_push($stuff,$row);
}
$ja = json_encode($stuff);
echo $ja;
```